# BIDS Debug Datasource vs Release Datasource

Tags: reporting-services, datasource, bids

In BIDS (VS2013 + SSDT in fact) I always need to change the server, DB, user and passord (the connect string) when I change from my dev env. to the prod environment.

Is there a way to use the DEBUG/RELEASE config so it selects the proper datasource ?